# How do I change the audio frame rate with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

From the man pages of `ffmpeg`:

```
-s[:stream_specifier] size (input/output,per-stream)
    Set frame size.

    As an input option, this is a shortcut for the video_size private option, recognized by some demuxers for which the frame size is either not stored in the file or is configurable -- e.g.
    raw video or video grabbers.

    As an output option, this inserts the "scale" video filter to the end of the corresponding filtergraph. Please use the "scale" filter directly to insert it at the beginning or some other
    place.

    The format is wxh (default - same as source).

[...]

-r[:stream_specifier] fps (input/output,per-stream)
    Set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation).

    As an input option, ignore any timestamps stored in the file and instead generate timestamps assuming constant frame rate fps.  This is not the same as the -framerate option used for some
    input formats like image2 or v4l2 (it used to be the same in older versions of FFmpeg).  If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.

    As an output option, duplicate or drop input frames to achieve constant output frame rate fps.
```

So these two options should change the frame size and frame rate of my audio stream, right?

Well look what happens when I fix the frame size to 1024 and change the frame rate:

```
$ ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -s:a 1024 -r:a 15 out.wav
...
size=    2592kB time=00:00:15.04 bitrate=1411.3kbits/s speed= 262x 

$ ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -s:a 1024 -r:a 30 out.wav
...
size=    2592kB time=00:00:15.04 bitrate=1411.3kbits/s speed= 277x
```

The audio duration doesn't change. I would expect the second audio file to be half as long as the first since the sample frequency and frame size is the same. What's going on here? How do I change the frame rate of my audio file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So these two options should change the frame size and frame rate of my audio stream, right?

`-s` and `-r` are video options, not audio options.

From the same documentation you quoted (`man ffmpeg`):

```
   Video Options
       -vframes number (output)
           Set the number of video frames to output. This is an obsolete alias
           for "-frames:v", which you should use instead.

       -r[:stream_specifier] fps (input/output,per-stream)
           Set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation).

        […]

       -s[:stream_specifier] size (input/output,per-stream)
           Set frame size.
```

Referring to `fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c`:

```
/* video options */
{ "vframes",      OPT_VIDEO | HAS_ARG  | OPT_PERFILE | OPT_OUTPUT,           { .func_arg = opt_video_frames },
    "set the number of video frames to output", "number" },
{ "r",            OPT_VIDEO | HAS_ARG  | OPT_STRING | OPT_SPEC |
                  OPT_INPUT | OPT_OUTPUT,                                    { .off = OFFSET(frame_rates) },
    "set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)", "rate" },
{ "s",            OPT_VIDEO | HAS_ARG | OPT_SUBTITLE | OPT_STRING | OPT_SPEC |
                  OPT_INPUT | OPT_OUTPUT
```

These lack `OPT_AUDIO`.

> How do I change the frame size/rate of my audio file?

I believe you are looking for the [asetnsamples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetnsamples), [atempo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo)/[rubberband](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband), [asetpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) depending on what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Number of sample per frame is determined by the coded and can be changes. Sample rate is measured in samples per second. Changing the sample rate changes the numerator, not the denominator.  Meaning it won’t affect time.

You are looking for the atempo filter if your goal is to speed up the audio.

Comment: Running `ffmpeg -r:a 30` clearly does something with the audio though. If it doesn't change the frame rate, what *does* the option do?

Comment: changes the sample rate. I.e. number of samples per second. It doesn't changes what a second is.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'simply' convert the current fps to the desired one using 'rubberband tempo' filter.
For example, to achieve a common conversion from PAL (25fps) to NTSC (23.97602398 fps => 24000/1001) would be:

```
23.97602398 / 25 = 0.95904096
```

So with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv  -af "rubberband=tempo=0.95904096" -vn out.mkv
```

You would also to apply a different most efficient codec.
For example keeping previous parameters with codec options: Opus, 224kbps VBR, 5.1 channels:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:a libopus -b:a 224k -vbr 1 -af "channelmap=channel_layout=5.1,rubberband=tempo=0.95904096" -vn out.mkv
```